# Convert DateTime to integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

while I am trying to convert the DateTime into int type I am getting timezone offset value as 0 in web API method, which has the value in the controller as today date time which is been assigned to a type of var in controller but api is expecting an int.

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Links()
{
    var timezoneOffsetValue = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;
    string requestUri = string.Empty;
    UserViewModel user = GetUser();

    if (user != null)
    {
        requestUri = string.Format("api/Link/getLinks/{0}", 
                                   user.TenantId, timezoneOffsetValue);
    }

    string response = await HttpClientHelper.Get(requestUri);
    response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);
    List<ViewModel> tagList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewModel>>(response);

    return View(tagList);
}
```

**Web API**

```
public async Task<string> GetTagsAsync(string tenantId,int timezoneOffsetValue)
{
    try
    {
        double offsetDifference = -1 * timezoneOffsetValue;
        string dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
        var dbInfo = await LookupConnectionByTenantId(tenantId, "");
        var result = await resourceTaggingRepository.GetTagsAsync(dbInfo);
        var Tags = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tag>>(result);
        foreach (var t in Tags)
        {
            t.CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(t.CreatedDate).AddMinutes(offsetDifference)
                                    .ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Tags);               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please never code `catch (Exception ex)`. It's a bad anti-pattern.

Comment: "while I am trying to convert the DateTime into int type I am getting timezone offset value as 0 in web API method, which has the value in the controller as today date time which is been assigned to a type of var in controller but api is expecting an int." - What?!?! - Perhaps you could clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity just to find the exception I kept. Thanks, i will remove it.

Comment: "just to find the exception I kept" - What does that mean?

Comment: i have  a method in the controller where i have  taken "var timezoneOffsetValue = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;" when i am passing the same parameter to the web api it is showing 0 for that. i am struck at converting it to int.

Comment: @MithunLucky, what actually do you want as `timezoneOffsetValue` ? did you mean offset like `+05:30` for India or etc etc, right?

Comment: Your API is bad. I live in a timezone that is +9.5. `int` won't cut it. You can do `double x = timezoneOffsetValue.TotalHours;`.

Comment: It looks like you are playing around with datetimes and timezones in the wrong way and the wring place. This always fails eventually. Why don't you just store all times in UTC, let your back end return all times in UTC and handle timezones (representation!) in your client?

Comment: If you want to convert offset make changes in controller  
`long ticks = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.Ticks;` 

and pass ticks to Web API. And in Web API convert back  

`var Offset = new DateTimeOffset(ticks,new TimeSpan()).TimeOfDay;`

Comment: "I am trying to convert the DateTime into int type" - In my experience, that's almost always wrong. **Why** do you want to convert it to int?

Comment: @er-sho yes. your right i need timezoneOffsetValue as +05:30

Comment: @MithunLucky, but +05:30 is not an `int` its string?

Comment: +05:30 can't be static right? in my web api do i need to make it static ?

Comment: @MithunLucky, you need to provide timezone and then timezone gives you offset

Comment: @MithunLucky, I added my answer with output below try it and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current time zone info by using `TimeZoneInfo` and then get total minutes from `TimeSpan` like

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

For example, if your current time zone is **India** then you will get **5 Hours and 30 minutes** from above code

**Output:**

[image]

And then If you want this time in minutes component then you can use `TotalMinutes` property of `TimeSpan` like

```
double totalMinutes = ts.TotalMinutes;
```

So above `totalMinutes` gives you `330` minutes, that means your time zone india is 330 minutes ahead from UTC

Or if you want to specify a particular time zone then you can get it like

```
TimeZoneInfo cst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
TimeSpan ts = cst.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

So above `TimeSpan` gives you offset from time zone `CST`

Comment: can you modify my code with your change? while i am passing the parameter from controller to web api  it is showing me as 0. can it  be without parameter in controller to web api?

Comment: you want your timezone as current or any specific?

Comment: try this in your controller => `if (user != null)
            {
                TimeSpan ts = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
                double totalMinutes = ts.TotalMinutes;

                requestUri = string.Format("api/Link/getLinks/{0}",
                                           user.TenantId, totalMinutes);
            }`

Comment: and this in web api controller's inside foreach => `t.CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(t.CreatedDate).AddMinutes(timezoneOffsetValue)
                                    .ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: what's the parameter need to pass from controller to web api? timezoneOffsetValue is 0 in web api but i have datetime in ts in controller. what papremter do i need to pass from controller to web api?

Comment: its a `totalMinutes ` paramter

Comment: "Total  minutes " in the controller is double but in web API it is int

Comment: change its datatype from `int` to `double`

Comment: still it is showing as 0 in web api, even i have the data in controller like datetime

Comment: ohh you made a mistake! you are not passing `timezoneOffsetValue` to api, you are passing only `user.TenantId` at placeholder `{0}` in url => `api/Link/getLinks/{0}`

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset` is of type `TimeSpan` and cannot be cast to `int`. Refer to [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

If you can establish some kind of base time, you could convert DateTime.Ticks to an integer representation.

Just a warning: DateTime.Ticks is of type Int64 (long), which cannot be squeezed into an Int32 (int), so you would need to decide what level of accuracy you want (minutes, days, etc.) and then get rid of the unnecessary component to fit the number into an integer.

To quote the documentation:
If the base time was December 14, 2007, at 15:23, the number of ticks since the beginning of the twenty-first century would be:

- 219,338,580,000,000,000 nanoseconds (Not gonna fit into integer)
- 3,655,643.00 minutes (That'll fit!)

For more information, see the documentation for [DateTime.Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2)
Here they use TimeSpan to get just the seconds.

```
long elapsedTicks = currentDate.Ticks - centuryBegin.Ticks;
TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(elapsedTicks);
Console.WriteLine("   {0:N2} minutes", elapsedSpan.TotalMinutes);
// 3,655,643.00 minutes
```